# Why does Hibernate persist an object of its own initiative?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have to see the bottom of that. Here's a brief abstract: I have a `Configuration` model object which has some configuration settings along with a username and a password. Of course, the password is encrypted and I have to decrypt it to use it. Pragmatically, I load the `Configuration` object with Hibernate (the password is encypted), I get the password, I decrypt it, and I set the password attribute to the newly evaluated plaintext (I use the setter mothod). Please note that I **never store the `Configuration` object** again. The weird result is that I found the `CONFIGURATIONS` table updated with the password plaintext in the db! I guess the Hibernate caching system has a role in the mystery, but I must understand *why* and *how*.

The details in the following:

I use a Spring framework, version 3.1.2 RELEASE

**servlet.xml**

```
    <!-- HIBERNATE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

**service**

```
@Service("configurationManager")
public class ConfigurationManager {

    //attributes and blah blah

    public Configuration loadConfiguration()
    {
        //the Configuration's password attribute is encrypted in the db
        Configuration configuration = configurationDao.load();
        if(configuration!=null)
        {
            //...to use the password I must decrypt it
            if(!(configuration.getPassword()==null || configuration.getPassword().isEmpty()))
            {                   
                String encryptedText = configuration.getPassword();
                String decryptedText = credentialsManager.decrypt(encryptedText);
                //after decrypting the password, I set the Configuration's password attribute to the plaintext password
                //I'll never ever store the Configuration obj with the newly set password.
                configuration.setPassword(decryptedText);
            }
        }
        return configuration;
    }   
}
```

**(maybe useless) clue:** I notice this Hibernate behaviour since I started to use AOP for different purposes. I can't see a clear connection between the two things, but I report anyway it. I included these libs in the project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load an object with hibernate, the instance is bound to the session you loaded it with, and keep track of all changes to it. When the session is eventually flushed (calling the appropriate method or internally due to FlushMode selection on the session behaviour) the changes are synchronized to the db.

Either do not change the object you loaded and store the unencrypted password in e.g. a nonpersistent attribute, or call *evict* to detach it from the session.

**Edit**: for some background info, see [hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch11.html), and in particular section 11.1 - hibernate object states - you can see there that an object loaded from a session is in a *Persisted* state, and that changes are persisted when the work unit completes (i.e. the session is flushed.

Comment: my choice is to declare a `private String plaintextPassword` with the `@Transactional` annotation. I use it to store my plaintext and I don't set the persisted `password` attribute anymore. It seems to work. Besides, you say that when the session is flushed Hibernate commits all changes... it makes the "storing methods" (`save()`, `saveOrUpdate()`, etc...) a little useless. One would call them only  to persist the object without waiting the auto-commit.

Comment: Not quite - take a look at the docs i linked - and in the API for Session it states (albeit not giving much emphasis on it) that the *save* and *update* (and *saveOrUpdate* of course) methods are used to persist the state of a **detached** instance - that is, one that you created anew or detached previously.

Comment: thank you very much for linking the documentation. I'm studying it right now.

Comment: You're welcome - actually there's  a correction to be made to my answer: it's the *FlushMode* selection, and **not** *autocommit*, that determines when the session is flushed. My mistake, and correcting it for clarity.